# Using Nominatim on Pandas full table

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, nominatim

I am trying to use Nominatim to loop on my Pandas dataframe Boroughs and get longitude and latitude for every Borough , I am trying this code which works only if table.head() which gets me only the first 5 rows filled but if I did this table['Boroughs'] it gets me an error of service not available

```py
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='my-app-location')
london_table = london_table_Borough.head().copy()
print(london_table)
location = london_table.Borough.apply(lambda borough: geolocator.geocode(borough))
london_table['latitude'] = [x.latitude for x in location]
london_table['longtitude'] = [x.longitude for x in location]
london_table
```

this works well but if I do this it give me an error :

```py
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='my-app-location')
london_table = london_table_Borough.copy()
print(london_table)
location = london_table['Borough'].apply(lambda borough: geolocator.geocode(borough))
london_table['latitude'] = [x.latitude for x in location]
london_table['longtitude'] = [x.longitude for x in location]
london_table
```

any idea what to do?

Comment: You likely exceeded Nominatim's stated maximum rate of 1 request per second (https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). Try rewriting your Nominatim calls in an explicit `for` loop with `sleep(1.1)` in it.

Comment: _it give me an error_ What error? Please share the entire error message.